# Sufficient sample size for longitudinal data analysis

Tags: repeated-measures, sample-size, generalized-estimating-equations

I have 30 subjects with 5 observations each. Is my sample size 30 or 150 and would it be sufficient to satisfy the asymptotic assumptions of regression parameters for GEEs